# Redis taking too much memory

Tags: redis, predis

I setup a Redis (version 4.0.6) sentinel cluster in two centos 6 VMs. Both master and slave Redis server has maxmemory set to 10GB and maxmemory_policy as volatile-lru.

The problem is, both servers are taking alot of memory.

## Master

```
used_memory:8959732536
used_memory_human:8.34G
used_memory_rss:14763728896
used_memory_rss_human:13.75G
used_memory_peak:10002148536
used_memory_peak_human:9.32G
used_memory_peak_perc:89.58%
used_memory_overhead:1344839894
used_memory_startup:761776
used_memory_dataset:7614892642
used_memory_dataset_perc:85.00%
total_system_memory:20957556736
total_system_memory_human:19.52G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:10000000000
maxmemory_human:9.31G
maxmemory_policy:volatile-lru
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.65
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

## Slave

```
used_memory:8927665872
used_memory_human:8.31G
used_memory_rss:16422535168
used_memory_rss_human:15.29G
used_memory_peak:10000009472
used_memory_peak_human:9.31G
used_memory_peak_perc:89.28%
used_memory_overhead:1340505548
used_memory_startup:761792
used_memory_dataset:7587160324
used_memory_dataset_perc:84.99%
total_system_memory:20957556736
total_system_memory_human:19.52G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:10000000000
maxmemory_human:9.31G
maxmemory_policy:volatile-lru
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.84
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

Redis is taking 14064.8 MB and 15664.2 MB on master and slave respectively. 
I do have alot of data stored in redis. Most of them has expiry set to them and some have no expiry.

The problem is even after setting max memory set to 10 GB why is redis taking around 15GB in the VM.

I see that used memory is below 10GB and the rss memory is 15GB.

I did run MEMORY PURGE which clears some of the rss memory but it gets re populated within a few minutes and keeps growing.

Any suggestion on how I can control the memory consumption or a permanent solution for this issue. Should I increase RAM in the VM? if yes how much RAM should I add to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0):

RSS memory will always be larger than the actual memory used by Redis for the dataset. It appears that, in your case, you're also suffering from memory fragmentation so you should consider enabling the active defragmentor.

That said, allocating more RAM to your servers will allow them to reach higher fragmentation rates, so the more you add the longer it will take to reach memory pressure. Since fragmentation is usage dependent, it is hard to say accurately how much more you'll need, but in most case fragmentation plateaus after a while so that should give you some indication.